# Is it a Regular Polygon?

Tags: code-golf, geometry

A [regular polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_polygon) is a polygon that is equiangular (all angles are equal in measure) and equilateral (all sides have the same length).

Your job is to find out if a given polygon is regular or not.

### Specs

- You will be given a list of Cartesian coordinate 2-tuples which describe the polygon's vertices.
- The points will always make a valid polygon.
- You have to return a truthy / falsey for whether or not the polygon is regular.
- Assume vertices are rounded to the nearest int.
- They might or might not be in order.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortest code in **bytes** wins!

### Test Cases

*Most test cases generated by [this site](http://www.mathopenref.com/coordpolycalc.html).*

```
[(1,2), (3, 2), (1, 0), (3, 0)] -> True
[(1, 1), (5, 3), (7, 7), (3, 5)] -> False
[(550,450), (455,519), (491,631), (609,631), (645,519)] -> True
[(106,81), (94,81), (84,88), (80,100), (84,112), (94,119), (106,119), (116,112), (120,100), (116,88)] -> True
```

Comment: Are the coordinates always integers?

Comment: Another question: Based on the examples, it looks like the vertices are not necessarily in order?

Comment: Surely a polygon with all integer coordinates cannot be regular unless it's a square? Are we assuming some rounding?

Comment: @xnor sorry forgot to mention, you're rounding to nearest int.

Comment: @RetoKoradi correct. they are in any order, updated question.

Comment: Are we allowed to take input as a list of complex numbers?

Comment: @ThomasKwa no, but the actual list of pairs can be varied in format

Comment: I think `(0,0),(0,1),(2,1)`->`True` is a good test case.

Comment: This question is unclear. How are we supposed to tell if the polygon is regular without knowing its exact coordinates?